Notifications not showing up as banner, only in toolbar (android PWA)
I am making a PWA and got to a point where I hear notifications and when I slide down, I can see the notification with title and body, but I wish it showed up on the screen as well, in the case where I am using my phone. Right now in this case the notification just makes a sound and I have to slide down from the top of the screen to see it. It does not show up as normal notifications do.
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  const data = event.data.json(); // Assuming the server sends JSON
  const options = {
    body: data.body,
    icon: "icon.png",
    badge: "icon.png",
  };
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options));
});

  const handleRequestPermission = async () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/service-worker.js")
      .then(async (registration) => {
        const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

        if (permission === "granted") {
          // Subscribe to push notifications
          const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true, // does not help
            applicationServerKey: import.meta.env.VITE_VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY,
          });

          // Send subscription to backend to save it
          await api.post("/api/client/push/subscribe", {
            subscription,
          });
        } else {
          console.error("Permission for notifications denied");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Service Worker registration failed:", error);
      });
    
    setIsNotifDialogOpen(false);
  };

